# How to use apply() on an array of matrices in R?

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, apply

I am trying to use `apply()` on an array of matrices.
Here is an example:

```r
data(UCBAdmissions)
fisher.test(UCBAdmissions[,,1]) #This works great
apply(UCBAdmissions, c(1,2,3), fisher.test) #This fails
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UCBAdmissions` data has six contingency `table` data within `Dept` part, namely: "A", "B", "C" , "D", "E" , and "F".

```
dimnames(UCBAdmissions)
#$Admit
#[1] "Admitted" "Rejected"

#$Gender
#[1] "Male"   "Female"

#$Dept
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
```

You can apply `fisher.test` to each of these six tables. It is not clear to me from your code `apply(UCBAdmissions, c(1,2,3), fisher.test)` to which part of the six tables you want to apply `fisher.test`.

If you want to apply `fisher.test` to the first three of the six tables, namely "A", "B", and "C", you need to subset the `UCBAdmissions` data first, and then set the dimension to 3.

```
apply(UCBAdmissions[,,1:3], 3, fisher.test)

# $A
# 
# Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
# 
# data:  array(newX[, i], d.call, dn.call)
# p-value = 1.669e-05
# alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  0.1970420 0.5920417
# sample estimates:
# odds ratio 
#  0.3495628 
# 
# 
# $B
# 
#   Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
# 
# data:  array(newX[, i], d.call, dn.call)
# p-value = 0.6771
# alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#   0.2944986 2.0040231
# sample estimates:
#   odds ratio 
# 0.8028124 
# 
# 
# $C
# 
# Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
# 
# data:  array(newX[, i], d.call, dn.call)
# p-value = 0.3866
# alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  0.8452173 1.5162918
# sample estimates:
# odds ratio 
#     1.1329
```

Another option is to replace `3` with the dimension name:

```
apply(UCBAdmissions[,,1:3], "Dept", fisher.test)
```

This will give exactly the same result as the previous code.

In another case, if you want to apply `fisher.test` to contingency tables between `Admit` and `Dept` for "A", "B", "C", grouped by `Gender`, you can use:

```
apply(UCBAdmissions[,,1:3], "Gender", fisher.test)

# $Male
# 
# Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
# 
# data:  array(newX[, i], d.call, dn.call)
# p-value = 7.217e-16
# alternative hypothesis: two.sided
# 
# 
# $Female
# 
#   Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
# 
# data:  array(newX[, i], d.call, dn.call)
# p-value < 2.2e-16
# alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

To show the part being tested more clearly, I reshape the data and then filter it so that I have male only students in depts A, B, and C. Then, I apply fisher.test to the data

```
DF <- UCBAdmissions %>% 
      as.data.frame %>% 
      filter(Gender == "Male", 
             Dept == "A" | Dept == "B" | Dept == "C") %>%
      pivot_wider(-Gender, names_from = Admit, values_from = Freq) 
DF
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
# Dept  Admitted Rejected
# <fct>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#   1 A          512      313
# 2 B          353      207
# 3 C          120      205

fisher.test(DF[1:3, 2:3])
# 
# Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
# 
# data:  DF[1:3, 2:3]
# p-value = 7.217e-16
# alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

The result is exactly the same as the one resulted from `apply(UCBAdmissions[,,1:3], "Gender", fisher.test)` for `Male` group.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:
Personally I do it this way:
First make a list `UCB_list`

then bind list elements to dataframe with `rbindlist` from `data.table`

finally, use `lapply` indicating the column `y=df$Gender` you want to iterate through:

```
library(data.table)
UCB_list <- list(UCBAdmissions)
df <- rbindlist(lapply(UCB_list, data.frame))

lapply(df, fisher.test, y = df$Gender)
```

```
> lapply(df, fisher.test, y = df$Gender)
$Admit

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  X[[i]] and df$Gender
p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1537975 6.5020580
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
         1 


$Gender

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  X[[i]] and df$Gender
p-value = 7.396e-07
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 16.56459      Inf
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
       Inf 


$Dept

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  X[[i]] and df$Gender
p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: two.sided


$Freq

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  X[[i]] and df$Gender
p-value = 0.4783
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```